# Change the value of div align left or right or center

Tags: php, jquery

is it possible to do it in jQuery AJAX

I have this div with the align center left or right

codes

```
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_one">
  <h3>Position of logo on the document</h3>
        <input type="hidden" name="c" value="cprof" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_code" value="<?=$_GET['ucom'];?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="com_code" value="<?=$_GET['ccom'];?>" />
        <?
        $get_position = SET_SQL( "SELECT * FROM jon_com_add WHERE user_code = '".$_GET['ucom']."' " );
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="position_id" value="<?=$get_position['a_id'];?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="position_change" value="chg" />
        <label>Logo Position : </label>
          <p>
            <input name="logo_position" type="radio" value="left">
            Left

            <input name="logo_position" type="radio" value="center">
            Center

            <input name="logo_position" type="radio" value="right">
            Right
          </p>
        <label>Logo Width</label>
        <input type="text" name="logo_width" value="632 x 128">
        <p>Format logo: <span id="logo_size">632 × 128</span></p>                  
</div><!-- .dropdown_menu -->

<div class="company_name" align="<?=$set_position['add_position'];?>">
    <strong><?=$set['com_name'];?></strong><br />
    <?=$set['address'];?>
</div>
```

it was connected to the database.

now my jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name=logo_position]').click(function(e) {
        $('<img src="images/ajaxLoader.gif" id="loading" style="width:auto;" />').appendTo(".company_name");
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag
        var uc = $( 'input[name=usercode]' ).val();
        var cc = $( 'input[name=com_code]' ).val();
        var l_p = $( 'input[name=logo_position]' ).val();
        var aid = $( 'input[name=position_id]' ).val();
        var p_chg = $( 'input[name=position_change]' ).val();

        alert(aid);
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"forms/tem.php",
            data: {ucode: uc, ccode: cc, logo_p: l_p, a_id: aid, chg: p_chg},
            dataType: 'html',
            target: '.company_name',
            success: function(data){
                $(".company_name").find('img#loading').remove();
                $(".company_name").html(data);
            }
        })
    }); 

});
```

What im trying to do here is that when i click the radio button of logo_position
on the `div class="company_name" align="left"` will change. for example i click center it should be on the center.

is my jQuery Ajax wrong?
It doesn't save on the database the only it save was left the first radio button. but when i click center the ajax will just read was just left.

Something like i was doing a live view. So when i change something it will also change the position the font and other thing when i just click...

is this possible to do on jquery?

Comment: I think you need to explain yourself a little better here. To me it just looks like your loading the returned content of your ajax call into the element .company_name

Comment: I think `$('input[name=logo_position]').val();` should be `$('input[name=logo_position]:checked').val();` But this won't solve your problem yet because your code will only display output from `tem.php` in the div with class `company_name` and will do nothing to the alignment

Comment: Also where did `$set_position` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for alignment of div based onclick of radio buttons:

```
$('input[name=logo_position]').click(function(e) {

//code for changing align of div for respective button click
$('.company_name').attr("align",$(this).val());

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb3tp/2/)